# Evaluate the summation $\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^i 4$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, summation, arithmetic

Can somebody explain to me step by step how you solve this problem.

> Evaluate the summation $$\sum\limits_{i=1}^n\sum\limits_{j=1}^i 4$$

This is what I did:

1)I did the inner summation which gives us $4i$.

2)I did the outer summation which is $4(1)+4(2)+4(3) \dots 4(n) = 2n(n+1)$

Comment: Where's the problem?

Comment: sorry new user, i edited it

Comment: It looks like you've already solved the problem satisfactorily. What exactly is your question?

Comment: @CardboardBox well for the outer sigma, I just reasoned it logically but I was wondering if you guys can give me the proof as to why 4(1)+4(2)+4(3)…4(n)=2n(n+1)

Comment: Do you know what $1+2+\cdots n$ is?

Comment: oh, I see this all makes sense now, thank you all for the quick help.